# Как в tkinter узнать какая у widget длина и высота

Tags: python, tkinter, виджет

Как в `tkinter` вывести высоту и ширину виджета? Есть ли такая возможность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть функция `.winfo_height()`(высота) и `.winfo_width()` (ширина)

```
import tkinter as tk


def func():
    x = button_place.winfo_width()
    y = button_place.winfo_height()
    print(x, y)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")
button_place = tk.Button(root, text='какой то текст', font='Times 15', command=func)
button_place.place(w=400, h=200)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Вывод:

```
400 200
```

---

UPDATE

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("800x800")
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='какой то текст', font='Times 15')
        self.button.place(x=8, y=8, w=200, h=100)
        self.update()
        self.func()

    def func(self):
        x = self.button.winfo_width()
        y = self.button.winfo_height()
        but = tk.Button(self, text='еще какой то текст')
        but.place(x=8 + x, y=8 + y, w=200, h=100)


root = Main()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Тогда почему при вызове в самом начале выдает 1. Я имею ввиду что, без 'func' оно возвращает 1

Comment: Я хочу узнать высоту виджета `_list_["height"] = len(lab)`(это высота) и через 8 пикселей поставить кнопку `but.place(x=8,y=8+ _list_.winfo_height(), width=22, height=23)`; и winfo_height возвращает 1

Comment: В принципе я решил проблему но только через `root.after(100,func)` где в функции через `.place()` ставиться на место куда надо

Comment: @оаавирыыва добавил пример с вашим добавление кнопки

Comment: Извини если немного достал тебя, кнопки должны появиться сразу же высчитывая координаты первой

Comment: @оаавирыыва обновил. Добавьте функцию обновление `update`